# add html in aspx

Tags: asp.net, html, for-loop

I have this for loop in ASPX

```
 for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            strFname += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["first_name"].ToString();
            strLname += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["last_name"].ToString();
            str = String.Format("{0} {1} ", strFname, strLname);


        }
```

I want that the Fname will be next to The Fname, and in the next row the same (until the last) 
Iwant that in every row the first name will be next to the last name (in every line only one Fname and one Lname)
and the same thing in the next row. how can I do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = String.Format("{0}&nbsp;{1}<br />", strFname, strLname);
```

Comment: "still don't work" is not a lot to go by (i.e. if you want help).

Comment: thank you for your answer. but can you help me with this problem?

Comment: what do you do with str variable after the loop?

Comment: ah, you don't need to concatenate strFname and strLname, change += to = in their assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Write` prints out to the HTML output stream. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585(v=vs.90).aspx

```
Response.write(str);
```

You can also use the shorthand notation for output

```
<%= str %>
```

or

```
<%: str %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Repeater` control is more suitable in your case. In its markup you may use `td` to show FirstName next to LastName and `tr` to show them in a row. See [example](http://dotnet-wpf.blogspot.com/2008/05/binding-datatable-to-asprepeater.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not display your full code, we are not sure how you are displaying this on the full page.  You can use a Repeater, Gridview, Listview, or some custom display container.

Below is an example of how to do it with a ListView:

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvData" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="phItem" OnItemDataBound="lvData_ItemDataBound">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Fullname</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phItem" runat="server" />
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><asp:Literal ID="litFullname" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void lvData_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  //Get the data item that was passed in, in this case which number for this row.
  var data = (int)e.Item.DataItem;

  //Create temp first and last names
  var firstName = "First" + data.ToString();
  var lastName = "Last" + data.ToString();

  //Display it to the listview
  var litFullname = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litFullname");
  litFullname.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```